# XPM behaviour when editing content with action (href and onclick-events)

Tags: experience-manager

I noticed some behaviour with XPM that is a bit weird. Here is an example where using an onclick-event for printing a page.

```
<button onclick="window.print();" @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.PrintButtonLabel)>
    @Model.PrintButtonLabel
</button>
```

When clicking on the link, or pressing space the onclick-event is triggered. If I am rendering links inside a DxaPropertyMarkup box, it will navigate to that link if I happen to click on the area containing the link. An editor probably don't want to actually execute the actions, they wanna edit the content.

I've been trying to figure out a couple of solutions for this:

1. Detecting wheter or not we are in XPM-edit mode and not rendering the onclick-event. I have been unable to find any code example that is related to this.
2. Blocking all href+onclick inside a DxaPropertyMarkup. I don't want an editor to navigate through the site or calling on events when they are editing a page.

Is there a way to do any of the above solutions or do you have something better in mind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a server-side method that allows you to check if you are in XPM mode or not. However, you can do this client-side, using some handly jquery function.
You can find this function here : http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/even-more-fun-with-experience-manager

```
/**
* XPM specific functions
*/
(function($) {
    // initialize global variable
    SDL_ENV.isInXpm = false;

    // check and set global variable
    $.fn.checkIfInXpm = function() {    
        // check via availability of Tridion objects
        if (typeof Tridion != "undefined" && typeof Tridion.Web.UI.SiteEdit != "undefined") {
            console.log("in XPM");
            SDL_ENV.isInXpm = true;

            // display elements specifically for experience manager
            $(".xpm-only").show();
        } else {
            console.log("not in XPM");
            SDL_ENV.isInXpm = false;

            // hide elements specifically for experience manager
            $(".xpm-only").hide();
        }
    }; 
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
    // wait 5 seconds after document ready (to complete XPM load) and check if we are in XPM (setting global variable)
    setTimeout(function() {
        $().checkIfInXpm();
    }, 5000);
});
```

You could use this to remove any onclick (or other attribute) to an element. To do so, replace the `$(".xpm-only").show();` or `$(".xpm-only").hide();` with whatever you wish to do. For example, this piece of code removes the onclick event of a certain element : `$element.prop("onclick", null);`

Comment: your javscript code looks a nice solution!

Comment: It's not really my code, it's Bart Koopman who wrote this script. But it's a nice solution indeed